# Fatal error: Declaration of GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\HttpDriver\Session::run()

Tags: php, neo4j, graphaware

any help here:

> Fatal error: Declaration of GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\HttpDriver\Session::run() must be compatible with GraphAware\Common\Driver\SessionInterface::run($statement, array $parameters = Array, $tag = NULL) in C:\xampp2\htdocs\testno\vendor\graphaware\neo4j-php-client\src\HttpDriver\Session.php on line 24

and this is the index.php in the main website directory

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->addConnection('default', 'http://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7474') 
    ->addConnection('bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7687') 
    ->build();


$client->run("CREATE (n:Person) SET n += {infos}", ['infos' => ['name' => 'Ales', 'age' => 34]]);
    ?>
```

the new composer.lock :

```
{
    "_readme": [
        "This file locks the dependencies of your project to a known state",
        "Read more about it at https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file",
        "This file is @generated automatically"
    ],
    "hash": "8a7fd6ec7a8e36f1df4da81b3692f259",
    "content-hash": "ddca89f178ed9a5ba5bb16a2b899c5a8",
    "packages": [
        {
            "name": "graphaware/neo4j-bolt",
            "version": "1.4.2",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-bolt-php.git",
                "reference": "6b0c0712a51751c8af4695ca129c88d3ab8555c2"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/graphaware/neo4j-bolt-php/zipball/6b0c0712a51751c8af4695ca129c88d3ab8555c2",
                "reference": "6b0c0712a51751c8af4695ca129c88d3ab8555c2",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "require": {
                "ext-bcmath": "*",
                "ext-mbstring": "*",
                "graphaware/neo4j-common": "^2.0",
                "myclabs/php-enum": "^1.4",
                "php": ">= 5.6",
                "symfony/event-dispatcher": "^2.7|^3.0"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "behat/behat": "~3.0.4",
                "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8",
                "symfony/stopwatch": "^2.7"
            },
            "type": "library",
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "GraphAware\\Bolt\\": "src/"
                }
            },
            "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
            "license": [
                "MIT"
            ],
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "Christophe Willemsen",
                    "email": "christophe@graphaware.com"
                }
            ],
            "description": "Neo4j Bolt Binary Protocol PHP Driver",
            "time": "2016-05-03 13:44:08"
        },
        {
            "name": "graphaware/neo4j-common",
            "version": "2.2.1",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-commons.git",
                "reference": "ed3eafedb5923bea7e8b15c71d0f5a860aed0b4e"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/graphaware/neo4j-php-commons/zipball/ed3eafedb5923bea7e8b15c71d0f5a860aed0b4e",
                "reference": "ed3eafedb5923bea7e8b15c71d0f5a860aed0b4e",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "require": {
                "myclabs/php-enum": "^1.4"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.0"
            },
            "type": "library",
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "GraphAware\\Common\\": "src/"
                }
            },
            "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
            "license": [
                "ApacheV2"
            ],
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "Christophe Willemsen",
                    "email": "christophe@graphaware.com"
                }
            ],
            "description": "Common Utilities library for Neo4j",
            "keywords": [
                "cypher",
                "database",
                "graph",
                "neo4j",
                "statement"
            ],
            "time": "2016-05-06 15:11:19"
        },
        {
            "name": "graphaware/neo4j-php-client",
            "version": "4.0.0",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client.git",
                "reference": "5fda8da9e46ef1b045721a265c42e3f430ec44c3"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/graphaware/neo4j-php-client/zipball/5fda8da9e46ef1b045721a265c42e3f430ec44c3",
                "reference": "5fda8da9e46ef1b045721a265c42e3f430ec44c3",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "require": {
                "graphaware/neo4j-bolt": "^1.0",
                "graphaware/neo4j-common": "^2.0",
                "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.0",
                "myclabs/php-enum": "^1.4",
                "php": ">= 5.6",
                "symfony/event-dispatcher": "^2.7|^3.0"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "phpunit/phpunit": "4.*",
                "symfony/stopwatch": "^3.0"
            },
            "type": "library",
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "GraphAware\\Neo4j\\Client\\": "src/"
                }
            },
            "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
            "license": [
                "MIT"
            ],
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "Christophe Willemsen",
                    "email": "christophe@graphaware.com"
                }
            ],
            "description": "Neo4j-PHP-Client is the most advanced PHP Client for Neo4j",
            "homepage": "http://graphaware.com",
            "keywords": [
                "bolt",
                "client",
                "cluster",
                "database",
                "graph",
                "high-availibility",
                "http",
                "neo4j"
            ],
            "time": "2016-04-21 12:32:48"
        },
        {
            "name": "guzzlehttp/guzzle",
            "version": "6.2.0",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle.git",
                "reference": "d094e337976dff9d8e2424e8485872194e768662"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/guzzle/guzzle/zipball/d094e337976dff9d8e2424e8485872194e768662",
                "reference": "d094e337976dff9d8e2424e8485872194e768662",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "require": {
                "guzzlehttp/promises": "~1.0",
                "guzzlehttp/psr7": "~1.1",
                "php": ">=5.5.0"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "ext-curl": "*",
                "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
                "psr/log": "~1.0"
            },
            "type": "library",
            "extra": {
                "branch-alias": {
                    "dev-master": "6.2-dev"
                }
            },
            "autoload": {
                "files": [
                    "src/functions_include.php"
                ],
                "psr-4": {
                    "GuzzleHttp\\": "src/"
                }
            },
            "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
            "license": [
                "MIT"
            ],
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "Michael Dowling",
                    "email": "mtdowling@gmail.com",
                    "homepage": "https://github.com/mtdowling"
                }
            ],
            "description": "Guzzle is a PHP HTTP client library",
            "homepage": "http://guzzlephp.org/",
            "keywords": [
                "client",
                "curl",
                "framework",
                "http",
                "http client",
                "rest",
                "web service"
            ],
            "time": "2016-03-21 20:02:09"
        },
        {
            "name": "guzzlehttp/promises",
            "version": "1.2.0",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/guzzle/promises.git",
                "reference": "c10d860e2a9595f8883527fa0021c7da9e65f579"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/guzzle/promises/zipball/c10d860e2a9595f8883527fa0021c7da9e65f579",
                "reference": "c10d860e2a9595f8883527fa0021c7da9e65f579",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "require": {
                "php": ">=5.5.0"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0"
            },
            "type": "library",
            "extra": {
                "branch-alias": {
                    "dev-master": "1.0-dev"
                }
            },
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\": "src/"
                },
                "files": [
                    "src/functions_include.php"
                ]
            },
            "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
            "license": [
                "MIT"
            ],
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "Michael Dowling",
                    "email": "mtdowling@gmail.com",
                    "homepage": "https://github.com/mtdowling"
                }
            ],
            "description": "Guzzle promises library",
            "keywords": [
                "promise"
            ],
            "time": "2016-05-18 16:56:05"
        },
        {
            "name": "guzzlehttp/psr7",
            "version": "1.3.1",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/guzzle/psr7.git",
                "reference": "5c6447c9df362e8f8093bda8f5d8873fe5c7f65b"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/guzzle/psr7/zipball/5c6447c9df362e8f8093bda8f5d8873fe5c7f65b",
                "reference": "5c6447c9df362e8f8093bda8f5d8873fe5c7f65b",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "require": {
                "php": ">=5.4.0",
                "psr/http-message": "~1.0"
            },
            "provide": {
                "psr/http-message-implementation": "1.0"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0"
            },
            "type": "library",
            "extra": {
                "branch-alias": {
                    "dev-master": "1.4-dev"
                }
            },
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\": "src/"
                },
                "files": [
                    "src/functions_include.php"
                ]
            },
            "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
            "license": [
                "MIT"
            ],
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "Michael Dowling",
                    "email": "mtdowling@gmail.com",
                    "homepage": "https://github.com/mtdowling"
                }
            ],
            "description": "PSR-7 message implementation",
            "keywords": [
                "http",
                "message",
                "stream",
                "uri"
            ],
            "time": "2016-06-24 23:00:38"
        },
        {
            "name": "myclabs/php-enum",
            "version": "1.4.1",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/myclabs/php-enum.git",
                "reference": "07da9d1a7469941ae05b046193fac4c83bdb0d7e"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/myclabs/php-enum/zipball/07da9d1a7469941ae05b046193fac4c83bdb0d7e",
                "reference": "07da9d1a7469941ae05b046193fac4c83bdb0d7e",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "require": {
                "php": ">=5.3"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "phpunit/phpunit": "4.*",
                "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.*"
            },
            "type": "library",
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "MyCLabs\\Enum\\": "src/"
                }
            },
            "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
            "license": [
                "MIT"
            ],
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "PHP Enum contributors",
                    "homepage": "https://github.com/myclabs/php-enum/graphs/contributors"
                }
            ],
            "description": "PHP Enum implementation",
            "homepage": "http://github.com/myclabs/php-enum",
            "keywords": [
                "enum"
            ],
            "time": "2015-07-22 16:14:03"
        },
        {
            "name": "psr/http-message",
            "version": "1.0",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/php-fig/http-message.git",
                "reference": "85d63699f0dbedb190bbd4b0d2b9dc707ea4c298"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/php-fig/http-message/zipball/85d63699f0dbedb190bbd4b0d2b9dc707ea4c298",
                "reference": "85d63699f0dbedb190bbd4b0d2b9dc707ea4c298",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "require": {
                "php": ">=5.3.0"
            },
            "type": "library",
            "extra": {
                "branch-alias": {
                    "dev-master": "1.0.x-dev"
                }
            },
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "Psr\\Http\\Message\\": "src/"
                }
            },
            "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
            "license": [
                "MIT"
            ],
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "PHP-FIG",
                    "homepage": "http://www.php-fig.org/"
                }
            ],
            "description": "Common interface for HTTP messages",
            "keywords": [
                "http",
                "http-message",
                "psr",
                "psr-7",
                "request",
                "response"
            ],
            "time": "2015-05-04 20:22:00"
        },
        {
            "name": "symfony/event-dispatcher",
            "version": "v3.1.2",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/symfony/event-dispatcher.git",
                "reference": "7f9839ede2070f53e7e2f0849b9bd14748c434c5"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/event-dispatcher/zipball/7f9839ede2070f53e7e2f0849b9bd14748c434c5",
                "reference": "7f9839ede2070f53e7e2f0849b9bd14748c434c5",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "require": {
                "php": ">=5.5.9"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "psr/log": "~1.0",
                "symfony/config": "~2.8|~3.0",
                "symfony/dependency-injection": "~2.8|~3.0",
                "symfony/expression-language": "~2.8|~3.0",
                "symfony/stopwatch": "~2.8|~3.0"
            },
            "suggest": {
                "symfony/dependency-injection": "",
                "symfony/http-kernel": ""
            },
            "type": "library",
            "extra": {
                "branch-alias": {
                    "dev-master": "3.1-dev"
                }
            },
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\": ""
                },
                "exclude-from-classmap": [
                    "/Tests/"
                ]
            },
            "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
            "license": [
                "MIT"
            ],
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "Fabien Potencier",
                    "email": "fabien@symfony.com"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Symfony Community",
                    "homepage": "https://symfony.com/contributors"
                }
            ],
            "description": "Symfony EventDispatcher Component",
            "homepage": "https://symfony.com",
            "time": "2016-06-29 05:41:56"
        }
    ],
    "packages-dev": [],
    "aliases": [],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "stability-flags": [],
    "prefer-stable": false,
    "prefer-lowest": false,
    "platform": [],
    "platform-dev": []
}
```

Comment: Yea, you have an error

Comment: @Confiqure Or zipcode

Comment: I am guessing here, but are you trying to override/subclass `run()` but are forgetting to add all the required parameters of the parent class

Comment: i edit the post
and no i done nothing to any other class

Comment: @Confiqure can u help ?

Comment: Hi, I'm the maintainer of this library, can you 1) rm composer.lock 2) composer update graphaware/neo4j-php-client 3) post the new composer.lock file Thanks !

Comment: the New composer.lock in the edit u can see @ChristopheWillemsen

Comment: Thanks, do you have the bcmath and mbstring extensions installed?

Comment: i had insatalled xammp and am sure it have the 2 extensions in it @ChristopheWillemsen

Comment: Please list the activated extensions : php -m

Comment: Seems like composer doesnt find the extensions

Comment: [PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
@ChristopheWillemsen
thos are the extensions and thank u alote

Comment: What is the php version?

Comment: 5.6 @ChristopheWillemsen

Comment: sir @ChristopheWillemsen am really stuck here plz help me

Comment: plz @ChristopheWillemsen

Comment: I cannot really help, it's 10+years I didn't use windows :/ the only thing I would try is to delete the vendor directory, delete again the composer.lock and redo a composer install.

Comment: am sure its not windows problem :/ @ChristopheWillemsen

Comment: Didnt say it was one, just I cannot reproduce :/

Comment: if u want u can login to my pc with teamviewer ? @ChristopheWillemsen

Comment: Sure, we can schedule that for thursday, christophe at graphaware dot com

Comment: i emailed u :D plz check it @ChristopheWillemsen

Answer (score 0):

i found way to let it work
1-first change this library to another library : https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp

2- befor you run the neo4j server go to options edit the first row

3- chang this line

## Require (or disable the requirement of) auth to access Neo4j

dbms.security.auth_enabled=true
to

## Require (or disable the requirement of) auth to access Neo4j

dbms.security.auth_enabled=false